# Laravel hasMany method not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 tables, `users` and `websites`.  One user can have multiple websites assigned to it.

```
public function websites() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Website');
}
```

The error I get is:

`Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany could not be converted to string`

If I try to output it as an array using `print_r` I get hundreds of lines of array which I'm assuming is caused by an error somewhere.

Also, why do I have to use `App\Models\Website` in the `hasMany` method if I specified at the top of `User` model `use App\Models\Website;`?

If I use just `Website` in the method, I get class not found error:

`Class 'Website' not found`

Not a big deal, but it would be much cleaner not to have to use the full namespace path.

The code in the controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use App\User;

class DashboardController extends Controller {

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------
        Dashboard page
    -------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    public function show() {

        //$user = auth()->user();
        $user = User::find(5);

        return $user->websites();

        //return view('dashboard');
    }

};
```

Comment: If you don't want to reference the full namespace in the relationship you can use the PHP 5.5 `::class` static reference. `return $this->hasMany(Website::class);`. As for your actual issue, how are you trying to use the relationship? What are you trying to achieve? `$user->websites` will return you a Collection/Array of results whereas `$user->websites()` will return you a query instance to query the websites belonging to the user.

Comment: I am just trying to get all websites that the user has.  I can get it working easily like this `$websites = Website::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();` but I wanted to use the cleaned method if you will and also figure out why said method is not working for me.

Comment: Have you purposefully put your models in `App\Models\`? By default they are just inside `App\` and so you would reference it like `App\Website`.

Comment: Also, I take it that your website table references the user who owns it in a column called `user_id` given you haven't specified a different column?

Comment: Yes I put all of my models inside `App\Models`.  Only one in the `App` is User which is the default model.  I might move that to the `App\Models` later too.

Comment: Yes that is also correct. There is a `user_id` column in the `websites` table.  As I mentioned in the other comment, I can easily fetch that info by using query builder.  I'm just trying to see why it doesn't work this other way

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `websites()` function itself is not causing the error. The error is coming from wherever you are using the function.

The `hasMany()` function returns an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` object. So, when you call `$user->websites()`, this will return the `HasMany` relationship object. Wherever you are using this function, you are then trying to convert that result to a string, which is the error you're seeing.

For example:

```
$user = User::find(1);
echo $user->websites();
```

In this example, if you try to `echo` the response from the `websites()` method, you will get the "could not be converted to string" error.

If this doesn't help you enough to resolve the issue, you will need to post the code that is calling the `websites()` function for anyone to be able to help further.

### Edit

"The controller doesn't echo the websites() method, it just returns it." Anything returned by a controller method is converted to a string. This is your issue.

Instead of returning the `HasMany` object, you need to return the results of the `HasMany` object. There are two main options: call `get()` on the relationship to actually get the results and return that, or use the relationship attribute instead of the method.

Option 1:

```
public function show() {
    $user = User::find(5);

    // call "get()" to get the results
    return $user->websites()->get();
}
```

Option 2:

```
public function show() {
    $user = User::find(5);

    // use lazy loaded attribute instead of using relationship method
    return $user->websites;
}
```

Both of the options above will return the same thing: a `Collection` of the `Website` objects. Since you're returning this from the controller, Laravel will convert this to a string, so your output will be a json array of json `Website` objects.

Comment: Ok I added the controller code as well.  The controller doesn't echo the websites() method, it just returns it.  When I changed it to `User::find(5)` I get the same error.  If I try to print_r the result, it literally outputs hundreds if not thousands of lines-long array which looks more like laravel system stuff than anything in the database.

Comment: @zen I have updated the answer to reflect the new information.

Comment: I think the problem indeed was not calling the get() method. I just added it and it returns the array as expected! *faceslamintodesk*

Comment: Any downsides of using option 2 vs. 1?

Comment: @zen No. Option 2 is basically a shortcut for option 1. If you have not eager loaded the property, accessing it the first time will lazy load the information. Accessing it a second time will just return the information already loaded. It would be a good idea to read up on this [section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) of the docs to better understand lazy/eager loading of relationships.

Comment: awesome!! You saved me. great explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I have a couple of possible solutions:

First, do you have the inverse relationship defined?

**User.php**

```
public function websites() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Website');
}
```

**Website.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

Second, have you run `composer dump-autoload` in terminal.

Note if you want a cleaner interface you can this if you are using >= php 5.5

**User.php**

```
public function websites() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\Models\Website::class);
}
```

or

```
use App\Models\Website;

public function user() {
    return $this->hasMany(Website::class);
}
```

## Edit 1

Do your models have the right namespace?

```
namespace App\Models;
```

## Edit 2

You could try 2 more things.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use App\User;

class DashboardController extends Controller {

    public function show() {
        $user = User::find(5);
        return $user->websites()->toArray();
    }

    // this one will query the database only once.

    public function newShow() {
        $user = User::with('websites')->find(5);
        return $user->websites->toArray();
    }

};
```

Comment: I did not have inverse relationship defined, but I do now and still returns same error.  I did also dump autoload.  Also in your answer, the files should be reveresed, i.e. `user` method should be in Website.php, and `websites` method in User.php.  The error still returns as `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany could not be converted to string`

Comment: Sorry, I was writing fast, i updated my answer per your comment. Also added another idea too.

Comment: Yea I do have the namespaces correctly as well. I might just have to get a profiler library set up so I can see more detail or might just go back to query builder and get the data myself that way since it works for sure like that.

Comment: @zen I think you are trying to return an object, and php is complaining that you can't convert an object to a string.

Comment: @whoacowboy Your first example will error out because relationship objects (e.g. `HasMany`) don't implement the `toArray()` method. Your second example would work, but is a little redundant since `toArray` will get called on the collection when it is converted to a string.

Comment: @whoacowboy Additionally, both examples will run two queries against the database. Since only one user is being found, there isn't any performance gain from eager loading the websites. However, eager loading is a good thing to know about, and a good habit to get into.

Comment: @patricus 1. The `toArray()` is not run on the relation, but it is run on the collection that is returned by the query. 2. The `User::with('websites')->find(5);` uses a join so only one query is run against the database.

Comment: @whoacowboy 1. Your first example is calling `toArray()` on the relationship method, not the relationship attribute. (i.e. `websites()->toArray()`, not `websites->toArray`). This means you're calling `toArray()` on the `HasMany` relationship object, which will give you a "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toArray()" error. Using the method instead of the attribute may have been a typo in your answer, but there is a big difference.

Comment: @whoacowboy 2. The relationship does not use a join. It uses a separate, second query. The first query will be `select * from users where users.id = 5 limit 1`, and the second query will be `select * from websites where websites.user_id in (5)`. When you get a chance, enable the query log on a tinker session and check out the queries run when doing relationship stuff. Also, you can go through the code to verify, as well.

Comment: @whoacowboy 2. The advantage of eager loading is so that the second query that is run is run once for all of the records loaded from the first query. If there were 5 users, and you did `User::with('websites')->get()`, the first query would be `select * from users`, and the second would be `select * from websites where websites.user_id in (?, ?, ?, ? ?)`. This loads all the websites for all the users in one query. If you only relied on lazy loading, it would run the website query once for each user object you access (hence N+1).