# Laravel Eloquent relationship not an object when doing anything but dd()

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have a seemingly stupid and crazy situation. I have activity logs for users, my user model has this relationship in it:

```
public function activityLogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Log::class);
}
```

Pretty straight forward and when I check a single user object for all logs it works fine. So on one page I only want the last log recorded, I need the `created_at` date from it. When loading the users I run

```
$users = User::with(
    [
        'activityLogs' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                  ->limit(1);
        }
    ]
)
```

and this returns the last log as expected. When I want to get the date if I run

```
dd($users->first()->activityLogs()->first()->created_at->format("d/m/Y"));
```

I get a string output with the date as expected. However, when I try to do anything else with it, such as putting it into a variable or echoing it out I just get an error that activityLogs()->first() is not an object. The code in my view (inside a `foreach ($users as $user)` loop) is

```
{{ $user->activityLogs()->first()->created_at }}
```

and it just gives me the error

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Trying to get property of non-object (View: **ROOT_PATH**/resources/views/acp/partials/profiles.blade.php) (View: **ROOT_PATH**/resources/views/acp/partials/profiles.blade.php)

I've tried accessing `activityLogs` as both a collection and hasMany object. I've also tried converting the resultant JSON string back with `json_decode` but it still complains about not being an object.

Why? Why can I get the value perfectly fine when using `dd` but when I try *anything else* it's suddenly a JSON string? I've tried googling this but no matter what combination of words I try it just comes up with questions and guides on how to convert an Eloquent object into JSON, the opposite of what I want.

Comment: From an answer I've seen here [Laravel HasMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571957/laravel-hasmany-method-not-working) have you tried `{{ $user->activityLogs->first()->created_at }}`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well.

Comment: You're already loading the activity logs with `with`, so you don't need to do all that. Try looking at the dump for your `$user` to see if the activity log is in there.

Comment: Have you tried removing the first() from the foreach as you are already pulling it in

Comment: @aynber Yes, the expected information is there.

Comment: @Rbaskam The foreach is only on the `users` collection. The `$user->activityLogs` is still a collection and so needs `first` running on it.

Comment: If it's there, then you won't need first. When you load `$users`, you're already telling it to get only the first activity record for each user with the `with` function. Use the dump as a guide to get the activity log's date.

Comment: @aynber but because it's a `hasMany` relationship it returns a collection regardless, it's just a collection containing a single object. I know it is because if I do `dd($user->activityLogs)` it says it's a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check to make sure the user has a last activity.  `first()` will return null if there aren't any logs. You should check for existence in your loop.

```
@foreach($user as $user)
    {{$user->activityLogs->count() > 0 ? $user->activityLogs->first()->created_at : 'User Has No Activity!'}}
@endforeach
```

Or use blade's `@if/@else`

```
@foreach($user as $user)
    @if($user->activityLogs->count() > 0)
        {{$user->activityLogs->first()->created_at}}
    @else 
        'User Has No Activity!'
    @endif  
@endforeach
```

Comment: It does, which is what I see when I use `dd($->activityLogs->first())` it shows me the correct record.

Comment: That's just the first user but you're looping through a collection of users and one of the users in the collection (not the first user) doesn't have any activitylogs.

Comment: Of course, why didn't I think of that before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There should be two ways you can go about it, since you're already eagerLoading it into a collection:

```
$user->activityLogs->first()->created_at
```

or

```
$user->activityLogs[0]->created_at
```

Comment: I've already tried that, I just get `Trying to get property of a non-object`. For some reason the Log object has been converted to a JSON string. Also you can't use `$user->activityLogs[0]` because it's a Laravel Collection, not an array.

Comment: I tried it locally and it worked, but I am using an older version of Laravel, and that can make a difference. *shrug*

Comment: Thanks for trying at least :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm late for the party here, but the problem is that one of your activityLogs is null and that's why it's breaking for you. I had the same problem now and figured it out.